# content should appear exactly in the middle of each wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress

iam bit new to wordpress. Actually I have 2 queries:

I have a shortcode, but how do i add this in a php file, i got an answer that we can use do_shortcode() function.

But my another query is, how do I use above shortcode, so that the content appears exactly in the middle of each post?

Could anyone please tell this? ( I already searched for this on google, but didnt found a correct solution yet )

Comment: Are you able to share any code you already have or tried?

Comment: what do you mean by middle? centered?

Comment: @Tom I mean my "ad" should appear in the middle of the content.

Comment: Are you using "return" in your function?

Answer (score 0):

This is how your short code should look

```
// Function to show ad
  function yourprefix_ad1_shortcode() {
    return 'ad code';
}
add_shortcode('ad', 'yourprefix_ad_shortcode');
```

then add [ad] to your post.

Comment: Actually iam not asking how to create shortcode, i already had a shortcode, but how do I use my shortcode so that it displays in the middle of my every wordpress post automatically.

Comment: I don't think that you understand the purpose of shortcodes, you don't need a shortcode you need a to add script to your template page that display the ad in the middle of the_content()

Comment: here, read this: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-break-the_content-to-insert-ad

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using short code, why don't you try to install Custom CSS plugin and try to find the exactly class or id and align-text:center?

If you are confused, Please let us know the URL of the page and we'll guide you further what exactly needs to be done.

Regards,
Raj.